# How Crystal Reports Reference rows in Details Section?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to know how Crystal Reports reference the rows in the details section. 
I used three formula
reset formula:

```
Whileprintingrecords;
shared Numbervar rowvalue1 := 0;
shared Numbervar rowvalue2 := 0;
```

Calculation formula

```
Whileprintingrecords;
IF recordnumber=1 then shared Numbervar rowvalue1:=rowvalue1+{table.total};
IF recordnumber=2 then shared Numbervar rowvalue2:=rowvalue2+{table.total};
```

display formula

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar rowvalue3:=(shared numbervar rowvalue2)-(shared numbervar rowvalue1);
```

I have only two groups and 4 rows in my report 
I place

```
reset formula in group header
calculation formula in group details section
display formula in group footer
```

and the result was:
[image]

in the second group the result of substraction was 0 why?
is crystal report work like that 
[image]
OR
[image]

Comment: Is your report grouped? What do you mean by select? Do you mean you only what the output to show row 1 and 44 or do you mean you need to select them for some calculation purpose?

Comment: yes my report is grouped and I want to select them for some calculation propose

Comment: Try manipulating using record number field

Comment: @Siva can you explain me how ?

Comment: Don't write answers.. if you have something then edit your question.

Comment: thank you Siva your solution work only for the first group but I have two groups in my report so I want to reset the recordnumber when it is in the second group ?how I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
NumberVar a;
NumberVar b;

    if recordnumber=1
    then a:=Databasefield;

    if recordnumber=44
    then b:=databasefield;

 Edit...............................
```

In group header create formula @reset

```
Shared Numbervar count:=0;
```

Now in detail write formula @count

```
Shared numbervar count;
count:=count+1;
```

Now write your created formula

The Reset Formula:

The following formula is to be place in your group header so it will             reset the variable on the change of each new group.

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar rowvalue1 := 0
Numbervar rowvalue2 := 0
```

The Calculation Formula:

I will Place this formula in the detail section.
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared numbervar count;

```
IF  count=1 then Numbervar rowvalue1:=rowvalue1+{column1}
IF count =2 then Numbervar rowvalue2:=rowvalue2+{column1}
```

The Display Formula

I will Place this formula in the group footer to display the result

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar rowvalue3=rowvalue2-rowvalue1;
```

Comment: Ohh sorry didn't see your response where are you struck...will try to help

Comment: thank you siva ,I have two groups,for the first group the substraction work fine but in the second doesn't work ! I edited my question for more details

Comment: Tell me every group has 44 rows ? I don't think so that Is the problem.... Though every group has 44 rows your formula will won't work because though new group starts... Row number won't be reset to 1.... Let me know your response for my first question.. Will provide different solution

Comment: No, I have only 2 groups ,inside each group I have 2 rows

Comment: I want do substract operation beween the two rows in each group and after shows result

Comment: Thank you siva your solution work fine you are the best :-) but in display formula I was forced to do Whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar rowvalue3=(Numbervar rowvalue2-Numbervar rowvalue1);is that correct

Comment: siva this is my last question :how to hide the values of The Reset and  Calculation Formulas in detail section thank you

Comment: No problem...always happy to help... right click on formula and go to format on first tab check supress...so that your data is not visible